# How to use scipy.optimize.minimize function when you want to compute gradient along with the objective function?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

`scipy.optimize.minimze` takes `obj` and `jac` functions as input. and I believe it will call them separately as and when needed. But more often than not we come across objective functions whose gradient computation shares a lot of computations from the objective function. So ideally I would like to compute the `obj` and `grad` simultaneously. But this doesn't seem to be the case with this library? What is the way to deal with it if one still wants to use `scipy.optimize.minimze` if at all there is?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You totally can. Just use `jac=True`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from scipy.optimize import minimize

In [3]: def f_and_grad(x):
   ...:     return x**2, 2*x
   ...: 

In [4]: minimize(f_and_grad, [1], jac=True)
Out[4]: 
      fun: 1.8367099231598242e-40
 hess_inv: array([[ 0.5]])
      jac: array([  2.71050543e-20])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 4
      nit: 2
     njev: 4
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([  1.35525272e-20])
```

It's actually [documented](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html):

> jac : bool or callable, optional Jacobian (gradient) of objective
>   function. Only for CG, BFGS, Newton-CG, L-BFGS-B, TNC, SLSQP, dogleg,
>   trust-ncg. **If jac is a Boolean and is True, fun is assumed to return
>   the gradient along with the objective function.** If False, the gradient
>   will be estimated numerically. jac can also be a callable returning
>   the gradient of the objective. In this case, it must accept the same
>   arguments as fun.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! It wasn't super obvious from the documentation/examples, and I feel like it should be given how important of a feature this is.

Comment: I would agree that the documentation isn't 100% clear. Ideally, it should say "fun is assumed to return a tuple with the first element being the function value and the second element being the gradient"