# Using python scipy.optimize.minimize with function that evaluates both value and gradient

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I want to find local minima of a function (of several variables) using python. The set of gradient-based optimization methods described in scipy.optimize.minimize seem like a good way to start.

I can compute the value of the function as well as the gradient of this function. As a matter of fact, when I evaluate the function, I basically get the gradient for free.
Is there a way to leverage this property to minimize the number of function calls using scipy.optimize.minimize ?

I'm only referring to methods that use gradient based optimization (say BFGS for instance).

More precisely, how can I plug in a single python function that computes both the value of my mathematical function and the value of its gradient into scipy.optimize.minimize ?

Instead of this :

`res = minimize(fun, x0, method='BFGS', jac=grad_fun,options={'disp': True})`

I would like something like this :

`res = minimize(fun_and_grad, x0, method='BFGS', options={'disp': True})`

Thank you !

Comment: Sorry ! I think this is a duplicate !
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734430/how-to-use-scipy-optimize-minimize-function-when-you-want-to-compute-gradient-al

I'm not sure what to do about the question though.

Comment: Does the duplicate answer your question? Then it can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Yes, although the answer my question has attracted is also relevant and interesting, and not present in the previous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom class that caches the gradient and then returns it when requested:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, x, *args):
        fun, grad = compute_something(x)
        self.cache['grad'] = grad
        return fun

    def jac(self, x, *args):
        return self.cache.pop('grad')


wrapper = Wrapper()
res = minimize(wrapper, x0, jac=wrapper.jac, method='BFGS', options={'disp': True})
```

Comment: Yes, caching is definitely clever. Although in this very case, the code would likely break down as many of the algorithms from minimize do not necessarily call gradients and function on the same evaluation points.